# How to allow only phone numbers in a text box and space them automatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Crazy long title is in an attempt to avoid getting flagged as a duplicate.

I have a textbox for entering a 10-digit US phone number, e.g. `222-333-4444`. I want the dashes to be added automatically as the user types more numbers, similar to the way Chrome treats a [box flagged as a date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cqz1.png). The slashes show up but aren't really... there. Typing 8 numbers fills the date box.

I also want *only* numbers to be able to be added to the text box, and no more than 10.

It seems like there must be a framework out there I could use for this -- there's no way this problem is unique.

What I have right now just inserts slashes occasionally.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textBox = $("#PhoneNumber");
        $(textBox).keyup(function () {
            var val = textBox.val().replace(/-/g, "");
            val = val.match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join("-");
            textBox.val(val);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far in attempting to solve this problem.

Comment: Checkout JQuery mask for this

Comment: *avoid getting flagged as a duplicate* ... *there's no way this problem is unique*... Which is it?

Comment: Use a mask of some kind. Even modern mfc have mask edit controls. I mean, you could hack it using event handler for onkeyup thing, but why bother.

Comment: @Mike There's no way the problem is unique, but none of the other questions I've found have been looking for the same thing as mine.

Comment: @Sinjai Can you explain why the duplicate I listed doesn't handle your problem? It appears to handle all of your requirements. If there's something in particular that isn't handled, your question should be updated to highlight this.

Comment: @deckeresq Sorry, I'm addressing comments one at a time. You're right, although the answer to this question proposes [this](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) mask plugin, whereas the one in the duplicate proposes [this](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) one. I'm not sure what the differences are, but I suppose one way or another the question is answered. I swear, I really did look for duplicates before posting. I guess I don't know the right way to phrase it.

Comment: @Mike To be clear, I meant avoiding being immediately dismissed, as I've found dozens of questions that just want the string to be formatted after the fact, or even as you type, by just inserting characters directly. I didn't want to be lost in the crowd.

Comment: @Sinjai No problem! Glad you found the correct one.

Comment: If you want to avoid having something closed as a duplicate, shows us you've found the potential duplicates and indicate why they didn't work for you. Note that mask plugins were mentioned in the currently assigned duplicate.

Comment: @Mike Thought I did. Oops. And yes, that's why I accepted the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUery mask is probably what you are looking for:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Once included then it is as easy as

```
  $('.phone').mask('0000-0000');
  $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
  $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
```